# @RabbitListener need to listen another queue that not created yet with another project in first time

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I need to listen queue from rabbit that implemented in another microservice.
assume in first time, we switch to communicate with streaming instead of rest and another application not started yet and it's queue not present in rabbitMq yet.
so `@RabbitListener` after see for example 'accountingResponseChannel.account' queue not present, try to create it, but that will be create by other microservice with specific option. as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602702/change-arguments-of-an-existing-queue) you can not modify exists queue, so this is not ok that I create a queue for skipping 404 error.

and finally my question is that how can mute `@RabbitListener` trying for create missed queue when queue not exists? because it face with error!

my related code if required:

```
@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
@EnableBinding(AccountProcessor.class)
public class SwitchStreamConfig {

    @Bean
    public Queue accQueue() {
        return new Queue(AccountProcessor.ACCOUNTING_CHANNEL, true);
    }

    @Bean
    public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }
}

public interface AccountProcessor {
    String ACCOUNTING_CHANNEL = "accountingChannel";
    String ACCOUNTING_RESPONSE_CHANNEL = "accountingResponseChannel";

    @Output(ACCOUNTING_CHANNEL)
    MessageChannel output();

    @Input(ACCOUNTING_CHANNEL)
    SubscribableChannel input();
}

public void transferMoneyStream(TransactionRequest transactionRequest) {
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(AccountProcessor.ACCOUNTING_CHANNEL + ".account", transactionRequest);
}

@RabbitListener(queues = AccountProcessor.ACCOUNTING_RESPONSE_CHANNEL+".account")
public void transferMoneyResponse(TransactionResponse transferOk) {      
     merchantRequestService.updateStatusAfterStream(transferOk.getTransactionId());
}
```

and yaml config:

```
spring:
 cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        accountingChannel:
          group: account
          binder: rabbitmq
          consumer:
            maxAttempts: 10
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          accountingChannel:
            producer:
              auto-bind-dlq: true
            consumer:
              auto-bind-dlq: true
              dlq-ttl: 5000
              dlq-dead-letter-exchange:
              republishToDlq: true
      binders:
        rabbitmq:
          type: rabbit
          environment:
            spring:
              rabbitmq:
                host: master_rabbitmq
                port: 5672
                username: guest
                password: guest
```

and exception:

```
Queue declaration failed; retries left=3

org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[accountingResponseChannel.account]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:722)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.passiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:607)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:594)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1357)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1202)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:129)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:125)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:147)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:1012)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1184)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy341.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:700)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'accountingResponseChannel.account' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:502)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:293)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:141)
    ... 14 more
```

version of libs ->   spring boot: `2.3.12.RELEASE`, and spring-cloud: `Hoxton.SR12`

thanks in advance.

Comment: ```RabbitListener ```  will check if queue exists, not ```create missed queue``` as you said

Answer (score 2):

Set auto startup to `false` on the `@RabbitListener`.

Use a `RabbitAdmin` (Boot auto configures one) to test for the queue being present - `admin.getQueueProperties()`.

```java
    /**
     * Returns 3 properties {@link #QUEUE_NAME}, {@link #QUEUE_MESSAGE_COUNT},
     * {@link #QUEUE_CONSUMER_COUNT}, or null if the queue doesn't exist.
     */
    public Properties getQueueProperties(final String queueName) {
```

When the queue is present, use the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` bean to start the container. Give the `@RabbitListener` an `id` and then `registry.getListenerContainer("listenerId").start()`.

But @mystery is correct; producers don't normally create queues; they send to an exchange with a routing key; they don't know about the destination queue. Although, to avoid message loss, it makes sense for the producer to declare the queue in many use cases.

Comment: thank you Gary.   i'm new with streaming :D . I may not have understood the subject correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Queue simply by

```
@Bean
public Queue accountingResponseChannelQueue() {
    return new Queue("accountingResponseChannel.account", true);
}
```

But you need to make sure other microservice component create binding with this queue with topic and exchange. Otherwise your listener will get no data in queue.

Comment: hi, as i mentioned, after you declare a queue, another microservice can not modify that. please see this 
 post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602702/change-arguments-of-an-existing-queue

Comment: That post said "The RabbitMQ broker will not allow declaration of a queue with mismatched arguments" But with same argument/parameter you can create Queue from any microservice. I do not see any problem with your case.

Comment: second microservice not create another one if queue exists. so first queue like you answered create with durable only and DLQ or DLK not modify with spring boot when second application start.

Comment: Creating Queue should be responsibility of the listener. I do not know why even second microservice creating this queue. If second microservice see that Queue already exist and skips then what is the problem? Your complete use case is not clear

Comment: in my business i need to send and listen like rest, but in my case i need handle it asynchronous with stream and covering timeout problems between microservices.  and about `Creating Queue should be responsibility of the listener`, i think This is not true for all cases. can you prove your point?

Comment: Cause sender send message to a particular Exchange and Topic, sender does not need to know any queue. On the otherhand Consumer consume from Queue (Queue get data from binding with Topic and Exchange). Also same message can be available in multiple Queue via different Queue binding with same Topic and Exchange